# How to generate unlimited string from keyboard

Tags: java

i need help for generating of unlimited strings from keyboard, but this don't work..

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

     String check=null;
      while(true){
          check = input.nextLine();
          if(check == "stop") break;
          al.add(check);

      }
      System.out.println(al);
}
```

}

Comment: `unlimited`?  and `doesn't work`?  I don't understand what you're trying to do or what problem you're having, but.... `if(check == "stop")` is almost definitely not doing what you want it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(check == "stop")
```

This is wrong and should instead be written as:

```
if("stop".equals(check))
```

Answer (score 2):

To compare objects in java use .equals() method instead of "==" operator

Need to change

```
if(check == "stop") break;
```

to

```
if("stop".equals(check)) break;
```

Comment: While your answer is not wrong, it is my understand that `"stop".equals(check)` is slightly better because `check` could be null.

Comment: Np.  :/  Except now your answer has more votes than mine.  :(  Haha.

Comment: If you're not worried about null then for fun you could also write it like this:  `if (check.intern() == "stop")`  By "for fun" I mean, "to drive your coworkers crazy" :)  Seriously, though, if you understand how `intern()` works then you'll have a good understanding of how Strings work in Java, or at least why `==` doesn't always work but sometimes does.